# Insert into table 1 update table 2 on button click in c# using access

Tags: c#, ms-access, multiple-tables

Ok, here is my problem.  I am making a new GUI for work. Nothing fancy, just something to enter information to be printed out on labels.  I have managed to get the code working to insert the values into the MainLabel table on button click, but I also need these to UPDATE just the first row in the Label table.

For some reason it will insert but not do the update.  how can I make that happen?  Here is what I have  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Updated still not working**

```
     OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Jim\Desktop\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\labels1.mdb;Persist Security Info=False";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd1.CommandText = "UPDATE Label SET SaleOrderNumber = @SaleOrderNumber, NsN = @NsN, NsNBarcode = @NsNBarcode, PartNumber = @PartNumber, Qty = @Qty, Description = @Description, CustomerPo = @CustomerPo, CustomerPoBarcode = @CustomerPoBarcode, PackingCode = @PackingCode, Weight = @Weight, Clin = @Clin, SaleOrderDate = @SaleOrderDate, MCM = @MCM, Cage = @Cage ";

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into MainLabel ([SaleOrderNumber], [NsN], [NsNBarcode], [PartNumber], [Qty], [Description], [CustomerPo], [CustomerPoBarcode], [PackingCode], [Weight], [Clin], [SaleOrderDate], [MCM], [Cage]) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,? ,?)";



        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SaleOrderNumber", label1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NsN", label6.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NsNBarcode", label6.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartNumber", label2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", label7.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", label3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerPo", label8.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerPoBarcode", label8.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PackingCode", label4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Weight", label9.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Clin", label5.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SaleOrderDate",label12.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MCM", label10.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cage", label11.Text);
        cmd.Connection = con;




        con.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

Comment: it goes down to cmd1.executenonquery(); and I get ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: it is surley because you have not initilaised your oleDBCommand object cmd1 with any connection object do as below: cmd1.Connection=con; before executing the cmd1.

Answer (score 1):

You're not executing `cmd1`.

```
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Side note, use all `IDisposable` objects in `using` statement.

Answer (score 1):

**Reason for Failure:** You are only executing the `OleDBCommand` object `cmd` but not executing the  `cmd1` where the update command is given.

**Solution 1:**
you have to execute the `OleDBCommand` object `cmd1`(update command) as below:

```
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**Solution 2:**

You can combine both insert and update commands into one string and execute once as below.

```
String command="";
command= "INSERT into MainLabel ([SaleOrderNumber], [NsN], [NsNBarcode], [PartNumber], [Qty], [Description], [CustomerPo], [CustomerPoBarcode], [PackingCode], [Weight], [Clin], [SaleOrderDate], [MCM], [Cage]) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,? ,?);";
command+="UPDATE Label SET SaleOrderNumber = @SaleOrderNumber, NsN = @NsN, NsNBarcode = @NsNBarcode, PartNumber = @PartNumber, Qty = @Qty, Description = @Description, CustomerPo = CustomerPo, CustomerPoBarcode = @CustomerPoBarcode, PackingCode = @PackingCode, Weight = @Weight, Clin = @Clin, SaleOrderDate = @SaleOrderDate, MCM = @MCM, Cage = @Cage ";

cmd.CommanText=command;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Note : Add Semicolon inbetween two commands.

**Solution 3:**
Create a function to execute your sql commands - which will take care of creation and disposal of your OleDB Connection and command objects .

```
private  void RunMyCommand(String SQLCommand)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection())
            {
                con.ConnectionString =
                    @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Jim\Desktop\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\labels1.mdb;Persist Security Info=False";
                con.Open();
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = SQLCommand;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SaleOrderNumber", label1.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NsN", label6.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NsNBarcode", label6.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartNumber", label2.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", label7.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", label3.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerPo", label8.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerPoBarcode", label8.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PackingCode", label4.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Weight", label9.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Clin", label5.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SaleOrderDate", label12.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MCM", label10.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cage", label11.Text);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

            }

        }
```

call the above function as below:

```
 RunMyCommand("UPDATE Label SET SaleOrderNumber = @SaleOrderNumber, NsN = @NsN, NsNBarcode = @NsNBarcode, PartNumber = @PartNumber, Qty = @Qty, Description = @Description, CustomerPo = @CustomerPo, CustomerPoBarcode = @CustomerPoBarcode, PackingCode = @PackingCode, Weight = @Weight, Clin = @Clin, SaleOrderDate = @SaleOrderDate, MCM = @MCM, Cage = @Cage ");
 RunMyCommand("INSERT into MainLabel ([SaleOrderNumber], [NsN], [NsNBarcode], [PartNumber], [Qty], [Description], [CustomerPo], [CustomerPoBarcode], [PackingCode], [Weight], [Clin], [SaleOrderDate], [MCM], [Cage]) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,? ,?)");
```

Comment: Sudhakar, I have tried this and I get this error {"Characters found after end of SQL statement."}

Comment: did you add the semicolon in string after insert command as shown in my answer ?

Comment: yes and that is when it threw that error.  I copied your answer and pasted it.  then I also tried to revert back the other way and execute cmd1 and got the other error

Comment: @xgonnahaveitx: please see my updated answer with sloution 3: Hope it helps :)